# Line break in list of inline-block elements, even with no html whitespace and box-sizing : border-box

Tags: css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5EXL/

### html

```
<ol><li>$100</li><li>$200</li><li>$500</li><li>Other</li></ol>
```

### css

```
ol { list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
ol li { 
    width:25%;
    text-align:center;
    background:pink;
    padding:20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

### output

[image: output]

### question

Why is there a linebreak after $500?  How can I get rid of it, while still preserving the `width:25%` directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't close the list-item tags, they autoclose. This will remove any whitespace you may put in there.
2. use box-sizing: border-box so that padding and borders don't affect the width of the list-items.
3. the margin property on your list-items is causing the line breaks. If you need white between the list-items, use a white border. It is kind of a cheat, but it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/t5EXL/13/

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li>$100
    <li>$200
    <li>$500
    <li>Other
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ol li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: pink;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 5px solid white;
}
```

Comment: i was already using `border-box` as the title and OP explained.  but thanks for the border hack for creating space -- works perfectly for me.

Comment: Item 1 is irrelevant. Item 2 suggests doing something that was already mentioned in the question (and in the title). Item 3 does not explain why there is line break.

Comment: Item 1 is a helpful tip to make the markup more readable. OP was going out of his way to remove white space and rendering the markup less readable, so I was offering a way for him to get around that. As for Item 2, although it is already in the OP's code, is a requirement for the border hack to work, though I did not make this clear.

Comment: I was quite confused, seeing as the inter-element whitespace wasn't demonstrated in the fiddle supplied with this answer, but I'm going to guess that it's because jsFiddle doesn't like missing end tags (which is ironic considering jsFiddle doesn't actually support XHTML in the first place), and that was causing the indentation to go haywire.

Comment: @BoltClock I put the whitespace back in there, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there a linebreak after $500?

because, all your `li`s are 25% of the total width, then on top of it you have added `margin = 5px` , there fore total width : 100%(25x4) + 20px(5x4).  which is more than total width : 100%.

> How can I get rid of it, while still preserving the width:25% directive?

Reduce `margin` to 0 :)
Add border instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a break because 4 times 25% plus any positive amount is more than 100%, so the boxes do not fit on the same line. You have set positive horizontal margins on them, and margins are not included in the width of the element even when using [`box-sizing : border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

So your requirements are self-contradictory, and you need to change them.

Comment: Any comment from the downvoters? This actually answers the question asked, unlike the accepted answer (which does not even mention margins as the cause of the problem, though it suggests a way to create spacing without margins).

Comment: @Jonah the tone is not condescending. Although this answer doesn't suggest a ready to use solution it is the only one to explain the root of your issue and therefore the way to understand/correct it by you.

Comment: It is inappropriate to edit another person’s answer in a manner that changes its substantial content. If you think you have a better answer, post it. My original answer, now rolled back, answers the “why” question and corrects the misconception expressed in the question title.